# Issue with IFRAME?

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem with iframe that too in chrome.
**How to make IFRAME transparent.?**

Comment: Is this really a question? Put some effort, show some code, what have you tried? error messages?

Comment: Yes. It would be very helpful if you told us more specifically want you want to achieve and what you have done so far.

Comment: @JuanMendes This may be not really a question for u.! But im trying this from past 8 to 10 days in all possible ways, this is not so simple issue. Try for embed video, i mean to say group of youtube videos which plays in list.

Comment: @RaviPrasad A question that is not well asked is less likely to be answered. In regards to "This may not be really a question for you", that is true, I do not answer questions that aren't well researched. If you look at the number of downvotes this question received, you'll see that SO agrees. All I'm saying is show your code, show an error, don't just ask a question

Comment: @JuanMendes <iframe src="..." allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe> in src it may be any video or swf link,

Comment: the error is overlapping with content in the page specially images and some times content of iframe wont display.. :(

Comment: Your code goes in the question itself, not in a comment, don't mean to be a pain, but it works much better when we all follow the same rules. The best thing you can do is create a reduction of the problem on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to get rid of the frames? Simple solution is to use `style´:

```
<iframe src="..." style="border: 0px"></iframe>
```

If your doctype is HTML5, you can also embed your iframe content seamlessly into the DOM (="transparent" iframe import):

```
<iframe src="..." seamless="seamless" style="border: 0px;"></iframe>
```

I wouldn't expect all browsers to support that yet though.

Comment: yes with attribute src="<any video link or an SWF link>" it will overlap with the content or some times content in iframe wont display.. :(

Comment: When exactly it does overlap and with what content? And when doesn't it display? With more info we could give you more help.

Comment: IE6 & 7 wont support html5.. !!!

Comment: I know. Mosaic doesn't support it either, neither does Netscape :) But seriously, please tell us: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Some time it'll overlap with images, when i scroll the page down,

Comment: Btw. seriously. Get rid of IE6. Even Microsoft wants it dead. Personally I would gladly see IE7 dead ASAP too.

Comment: but some people still using IE6 & 7, so i am try to work on that but every time failure occurs, is their any way to overcome this problem??

Comment: if so Please suggest me.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't know what your problem is.

Comment: problem is with iframe in IE6,7 and chrome for background transparency.??

Comment: Oh right. I think I got a hang of your problem now. I don't know why it doesn't work on Chrome, but it pretty much impossible to have an iframe with transparent background on IE6 and IE7. `allowtransparency="true"` could help though.

Comment: Ok. I'll try for last time with this attribute allowtransparency="true".

Answer (score -1):

Im geussing you mean, how do I make it so that the background of a page be transparent. That way it just shares the background of your page. If thats it, try this

```
<IFRAME ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true">
```

This will allow it to be transparent as long as the page you load has no background.

Comment: ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" it is not working.. :'(

Comment: could you edit your question to include the source code for the iframe and for the page your loading?

Comment: <iframe src="..." allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>